# How to call two functions after angularjs after service success

Tags: angularjs

In angular JS 1.6 how to call the two functions simultaneously after we get the success response from service. Is it possible ?

Comment: Please, show us some code of what you are specifically trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap both function within `.success()`:

```
this.myPromise().success((response) => {
    this.myFunctionOne(response);
    this.myFunctionTwo(response);
})
```

This way, `.success()` will fire *two* functions.

---

But actually, I have no idea if this is what you were asking for..

Comment: Thank you i got the solution